# SQL transaction management in Node.js with MySQL: use the existing transaction or create a new one if none exists

Tags: mysql, node.js, transactions

I'm trying to implement a SQL transaction management in Node.js, that would append queries to an existing transaction if available, or create a new one if none exists yet, thanks to an optional 
`connection` parameters. I'm using the [`mysql`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) NPM package, and after having had a look to their (rather small) [section about transactions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#transactions), I came up with the following:

```js
import mysql from "mysql";

const pool = mysql.createPool({
  ...
});

const _getConnection = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  pool.getConnection((error, connection) => {
    if (error) {
      reject(error);
    } else {
      resolve(connection);
    }
  });
});

const _beginTransaction = (connection) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  connection.beginTransaction((error) => {
    if (error) {
      reject(error);
    } else {
      resolve();
    }
  });
});

const _commitTransaction = (connection) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  connection.commit((error) => {
    if (error) {
      reject(error);
    } else {
      resolve();
    }
  });
});

const _rollbackTransaction = (connection) => new Promise((resolve) => {
  connection.rollback(resolve);
});

const _transactional = async (run, retry = true) => {
  const connection = await _getConnection();
  await _beginTransaction(connection);
  try {
    const result = await run(connection);
    await _commitTransaction(connection);
    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    await _rollbackTransaction(connection);
    const errorCode = error && error.code;
    if ("ER_LOCK_DEADLOCK" === errorCode && retry) {
      return _transactional(run, false);
    } else {
      throw error;
    }
  } finally {
    connection.release();
  }
};

export const transactional = (run) => async (...args) => {
  if (args.length) {
    const lastArg = args[args.length - 1];
    if (lastArg && "PoolConnection" === lastArg.constructor.name) {
      return run(...args);
    }
  }
  return _transactional(async (connection) => run(...[...args].concat(connection)));
};

export const query = (sql, values, connection) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  connection.query(sql, values, (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      reject(error);
    } else {
      resolve(results);
    }
  });
});
```

Now, in some other file:

```js
import { transactional, query } from "./..."

export const fn1 = transactional(async (x, y, z, connection) => {
  const result = await query("...", [x, y], connection);
  return query("...", [result.id, z], connection);
});

export const fn2 = transactional(async (x, y, z, connection) => {
  // passing the connection instance to fn1,
  // so that it does not create a new transaction,
  // but rather use the one created by fn2
  // (where this connection instance comes from):
  await fn1(x, y, z, connection); 
  return query("...", [], connection);
});
```

Finally, in some other file again:

```js
// fn1 will create its own transaction since none is passed:
await fn1(x, y, z);

// fn2 will create its own transaction since none is passed,
// but when it calls fn1, that same transaction will be used:
await fn2(x, y, z);
```

---

This seems to do the job quite nicely so far, but we aren't really under heavy load yet, more in a kind of "beta-live" state at the moment.

So the question is, will it scale? Do you see any issue with this implementation? I don't like reinventing square wheels, but I couldn't find such implementation already.

Comment: Your using pool connections, that is one of the ways to avoid the pitfalls of what I was saying in SO, didn't notice in SO you was using a Pool.  I personally use a single connection and handle concurrency inside node.  But the only thing I would say about the code above, I personally would use a separate `try finally` for your `_getConnection` because if `_beginTransaction` fails for any reason you will leak connections.

Comment: @Keith, interesting! So with a single `connection`, you can't really use SQL transactions though, can you? You'll face contention and locking issues as soon as concurrency occurs otherwise I guess? Would you mind providing a small overview of how this single-connection approach would look like?

Comment: Yes, you just have to serialise access to the connection, I just use a global promise for this.  You can also mix this with pooling too.  To be honest not sure if this gives any more performance gains or not.  The reason I use this approach is because I can use with other DB's too, like SQLite where I've found transaction handling to be a bit harsh.

Comment: @Keith Oh ok, fair enough :) But good point about the `finally`, I'll move the call to `_beginTransaction` inside the `try` block (not sure why I didn't do it in the first place to be honest).